# $pull entire 2D array row - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm able to `$addToSet` a 2d array without it creating duplicates no problem, but if I want to remove an item from my list via `$pull` it never removes the row from mongodb document. The 2d array is structured like this:

```
inviteGroup: {
    biddingUserId: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  },
```

In addition to the code below, I also tried to `$pull` line of code to this with `req.body.userId` representing `biddingUserId` from model above

```
        $pull: { inviteGroup: { $in: [req.body.userId]} }
```

but that didn't seem to work. How can I remove a 2D array row? I appreciate any help with this!

Here's a screenshot of what the collection looks like in mongodb, which matches the model.
[image]

```
   Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $pull: { inviteGroup: req.body.userInvited }
      },
      function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
          console.log(err);

          context.res = {

            status: 500,

            body: {
              message: "Add Invite Error!",
              error: err

            },

            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
              "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
              "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

          };

          context.done();



        } else {
          context.res = {

            status: 200,

            body: {
              message: "User Invited Successfully!",
              error: err

            },

            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
              "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
              "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

          };

          context.done();

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working example -

Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecc1c6af2a26b884f4272eb"),
    "inviteGroup" : [
        [
            {
                "biddingUserId" : "3",
                "username" : "name3"
            },
            {
                "biddingUserId" : "2",
                "username" : "name2"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "biddingUserId" : "1",
                "username" : "name1"
            },
            {
                "biddingUserId" : "4",
                "username" : "name4"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

}

Note the use of double $elemMatch to reach the nested array and use positional operator to identify the outer array element with $pull to remove the inner array element on query criteria.

Mongoose Code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});
const InviteGroupSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
   inviteGroup : [[{
    biddingUserId: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  }]]
})
const InviteGroup = mongoose.model('InviteGroup', InviteGroupSchema, 'invitegroups');

module.exports = {
    InviteGroup
}


InviteGroup.findOneAndUpdate(
 {
   "_id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ecc1c6af2a26b884f4272eb"), 
   "inviteGroup": {"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"biddingUserId":"4"}}}
 }, 
 {"$pull":{"inviteGroup.$":{"biddingUserId":"4"}}}, 
 {"new":true} ).exec((err, results) => {console.log("Results " +  JSON.stringify(results));}
)
```

Output

```
{
  "inviteGroup":[
    [
      {"biddingUserId":"3","username":"name3"},
      {"biddingUserId":"2","username":"name2"}
    ],
    [ {"biddingUserId":"1","username":"name1"}
    ]
  ],
"_id":"5ecc1c6af2a26b884f4272eb"
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to https://pastebin.com/vrzqkVV0 but it only returns ```Results null``` I'm a little confused about the ```4``` next to ```biddingUserId``` and what that represents. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry please dont use 4 that is just my value - use your id. In your case I think it should be `req.body.bidderId` instead of 4.

Comment: I think this should work for you - `Post.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) , "inviteGroup": {"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"biddingUserId":req.body.bidderId }}}},  {"$pull":{"inviteGroup.$":{"biddingUserId":req.body.bidderId}}}, 
 {"new":true} ).exec((err, results) => {console.log("Results " +  JSON.stringify(results));}
)`

Comment: That code returns the entire collection stringified to the console as you would expect, but the database never removes the row from inviteGroup.

Comment: Not sure - could you please share your document and code ? Also share the mongoose debug output so we know what  query was sent to mongodb. Btw the code should return the updated document not the old document as we are sending the new:true option while updating.

Comment: Here's the document: https://postimg.cc/HJm0pknw The code I'm using is identical to the code you left ```Post.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) , "inviteGroup": {"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"biddingUserId":req.body.bidderId }}}}, {"$pull":{"inviteGroup.$":{"biddingUserId":req.body.bidderId}}}, {"new":true} ).exec((err, results) => {console.log("Results " + JSON.stringify(results));} )```

Comment: Sorry this works for me. I’ve also have posted working example. It could be you have  incorrect arguments or mismatch types. If you could show me document before update , expected document after update and all the arguments sent. Also mongoose query which you can get by setting mongoose.set(“debug”, true).

Comment: mongoose.set("debug", true) outputs ```Mongoose: listings.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5ecbde520da4d559f4239358"), inviteGroup: { '$elemMatch': { '$elemMatch': { biddingUserId: '5ec00689f70f262a00aa7d4c' } } } }, { new:
true, projection: {} })``` The document before update is the example in original question. If I remove joe, then after update would look like https://postimg.cc/SnWWStPw. Array 1 from original question picture would be gone

Comment: Thank you - The biddingUserId in the query doesn't match from the biddingUserId in the original picture from your post but I'm assuming you are sending the correct id which may no longer be the same as what you have in original image.  This is findOne query - Where is the findOneAndUpdate query ? Your query doesn't have the update part where we use $pull commands.

Comment: I'm not really too sure why it says that. I have the code setup in this order: https://pastebin.com/cFJcujc0

Answer (score 1):

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
   Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $pull: { inviteGroup: {biddingUserId : ObjectId(req.body.userInvited.biddingUserId) }}
      },
      function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
          console.log(err);

          context.res = {

            status: 500,

            body: {
              message: "Add Invite Error!",
              error: err

            },

            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
              "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
              "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

          };

          context.done();



        } else {
          context.res = {

            status: 200,

            body: {
              message: "User Invited Successfully!",
              error: err

            },

            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
              "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
              "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

          };

          context.done();

        }
      });
```

Comment: I get  ```ObjectId is not defined```

Comment: You write this line? var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

Comment: I tried ```ObjectId``` and I also did it like ```$pull: { inviteGroup: {biddingUserId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userInvited) }}```, but it returns ```Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters```

Comment: Print and check req.body.userInvited, it's not a valid mongodb id

Comment: In your question at one point you have also written req.body.userId

Comment: ```req.body.userInvited``` outputs: ```[ { biddingUserId: '5ec2caa9d6335c6d8ce099e6', username: 'bob' } ]```  I also tried the following: https://pastebin.com/HtKGCCCP  but issue still persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214280/discussion-between-puneet-singh-and-user6680).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false 
})

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    inviteGroup: [{
        biddingUserId: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true },
        username: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
    }],
});
const Post = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)

//Example data
var post1 = new Post({
    _id: ObjectId('5ecbf32fba4c9d4c34ea829b'),
    inviteGroup: [
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfec14cc7af2bf043134f', username: 'bob1' },
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfec14cc7af2bf0431351', username: 'bob2' },
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfe0102aa1921bcee9092', username: 'bob3' },
    ]
});
var post2 = new Post({
    _id: ObjectId('5ecbf32fba4c9d4c34ea829e'),
    inviteGroup: [
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfc3663dfea3ccc5e6b5e', username: 'joe1' },
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfc3663dfea3ccc5e6b5f', username: 'joe2' },
        { biddingUserId: '5ecbfc3663dfea3ccc5e6b5d', username: 'joe3' },
    ]
});


Post.create([post1, post2]).then(docs => {
    //The docs are now saved to MongoDB.
    console.log('Number of docs => ' + docs[0].inviteGroup.length);// length = 3
    //Let's delete username=bob2 whose biddingUserId=5ecbfec14cc7af2bf0431351 from the first document
    return Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: '5ecbf32fba4c9d4c34ea829b' },
        { $pull: { inviteGroup: { biddingUserId: '5ecbfec14cc7af2bf0431351' } } }
    )
}).then(doc=> {
    //Let's verify that the user is removed
    return Post.findById(doc._id)
}).then(doc=> {
    console.log(doc.inviteGroup); // Contains only two users (bob1 and bob3)
    console.log('Number of docs => ' + doc.inviteGroup.length);// length = 2
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
})
```

**Note:** if you were verifying that the document is removed from MongoDB using MongoDB compass (for example),
don't forget to refresh the collection

Comment: I followed your example, but when I try it, the row in the array doesn't get removed. It throws a status 200 so I don't see any error message indicating what could be the issue. Updated code and output: https://pastebin.com/XQcYpG1E  Does it have something to do with the struct of having an object inside an array like in pic from original question?

Comment: Having objects inside the array is not the issue, I tested this an it works. The `req.params.id` must correspond to the document `_id` containing the array `inviteGroup`, I think this may be the issue. Here is how a document may look like https://pastebin.com/7CSkUvUy. And in MongoDB https://imgur.com/a/DfmZUOK

Comment: I Noticed `inviteGroup` is a 2D array as you mentionned, so this won't work, try @sagar-veeram solution

Comment: This is what it looks like when I do Post.findOne ```{"inviteGroup":[[{"biddingUserId":"5ec2caa9d6335c6d8ce099e6","username":"bob"}]]}``` which matches image from above: https://postimg.cc/14KYNbwc

Comment: I tried his solution, but it's not working yet. See comment under his answer

Comment: Please, can you show a full document containing `inviteGroup` ?

Comment: Do you mean the console output of the full document. This is what it looks like when not stringified if that helps ```{ inviteGroup: [ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ]```